# Drupal 8 subtheming, how to get parent's elements

Tags: drupal-8

I'm actually working on Drupal 8 subtheming, however I can't find good  documentation about it since it is recent I guess... So I ask here to see if someone knows about this.
My question is, once I have created my sub theme, and I want to add my custom css styles, what is the correct way to find or get the parent's elements or regions that can be customizable? for example, the way I am adding my custom css styles, is by right clicking on the site and Inspecting it's code, so I can find the region/element names and override them.
Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the D8 documentation is still catching up a bit. Are you trying to figure out how to override the styles by attaching your own style sheets, or looking for suggestions about ways to look up the right selectors?

Comment: yeah it is, how to properly get the right selectors